# How to test when creating Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am  making a gem, but how to test(not unit test, just make sure the program is right) it ?

Need I pack it and run every time when I modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a rake task to open a new IRB instance and play with your library.
[Here's the code](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/09/rake-console/).

Comment: That's a really neat idea. @why: I would say that you should pack and install every time that you modify a script in the bin directory of your gem, but ideally those scripts should have so little code that you rarely do edit them.